# Android Device UDID or unique ID?

Tags: android

I want to generate android device unique id for my android application to create favourite according to user device udid.

Comment: In case the user uninstalls your app, all data will be removed as well. So you will always have the time when the user installs the app. You can use it as an UID.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All devices have a unique id.

```
 import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
 private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                            Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: It's great. I didn't know this.

Comment: Be aware that while Secure.ANDROID_ID will generate a one-time unique ID when the device is booted the very first time, this ID will be lost should the device ever be reset to its factory defaults. A better solution is to rely upon the device's MAC address, assuming of course the device has Wi-Fi support, which practically all devices these days do.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String uDiD = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use different values as udid.
The above mentioned Secure.ANDROID_ID has some cons
It can be null
It is same on 2.2 and some 4.2 devices
You can use MacAddress of device or IMIE address(Can be null on devices without cellular connection)