# Something unique on android you can't change

Tags: android, mac-address, imei

I'm doing an application, for the trial version I have to recognize phone from something like IMEI or MAC address, but if you are good you can spoof them, so is there something on Android that doesn't change at all? Thank you

Comment: there is something called UDID which is generated on boot and it only cleared when device reset to its factory defaults. So you can use it if it matches your requirement. Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292411/android-device-udid-or-unique-id) to which tells how to generate it.

Comment: maybe I could take 3 or 4 parameters so I'm sure you don't waste your time to change them all.

Comment: yes , the link I shared, one guy suggested to use MAC address, So probably you can combine both of them so that it will be less likely to get duplicated.

Comment: thank you, maybe also imei and serial number, because i want to put a maximum of day of trial from the server

Comment: yeah that will do.

Answer (score 0):

there is something called `UDID` which is generated on boot and it only cleared when device reset to its factory defaults. So you can use it if it matches your requirement. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292411/android-device-udid-or-unique-id) to which tells how to generate it.

Comment: thank you, but i think this apk could change it [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=882596). And it isn't unique, thank you.

Comment: I can't put the feedback because I'm under 15 of reputation, sorry.

Comment: its okay you can dig more on this.